# Removing Lead from surfaces/floors

Tags: soldering

I have been doing some soldering in my garage, and because of my solder sucker, there is a some lead dust/powder on the table and floor. What would be the best methods for cleaning up as much of this as possible.

I ruled out vacuuming for the worry of spreading, and I do not have a shop-vac, so I cannot just wet the floor and suck it all up.

The best bet that I can think of is to just get a damp towel, and dab the affected surfaces, afterwards throwing the towel in the wash for an extra long run.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If it were my garage I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It's right in front of the tools, and it is fairly powdery (my solder sicker makes it so for some reason) so I am just trying to play it safe.

Comment: What solder sucker makes "powder" out of the solder?

Comment: Buy a shop vac with a HEPA filter. Also, consider using lead free solder.

Comment: How about one of those sticky paper rollers you use for picking pet hair off clothing? Cheap as chips in budget stores.

Comment: @JRE I don't know how to describe it. Flakes might be better. It was a cheap $10 sucker.

Comment: I have seen this, too. Also, the solder sponge (I use the gold colored type that is not wet) produces small solder particles.